# when i'm joining 4 to 5 tables in spark sql using scala its getting stackOverflowError

Tags: apache-spark-sql

```
val joined = s_order.as('so)
  .join(s_order_item.as('soi), 
    $"so.ROW_ID" === $"soi.ORDER_ID")
  .join(s_product.as('sp), 
     $"soi.PROD_ID" === $"sp.ROW_ID")
  .join(s_order_type.as('sot), 
    $"so.ORDER_TYPE_ID" === $"sot.ROW_ID")
  .join(s_order_x.as('sox), 
    $"so.ROW_ID" === $"sox.PAR_ROW_ID")
```

error:

> java.lang.stackOverFlowError